# Adding autopct Inline

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

How do you add autopct inline?

This one here displays the pie chart

```
marital_chart = market_survey_marital["MARITAL STATUS"].value_counts().plot(kind='pie')
```

But adding autopct below displays an error.

```
marital_chart = market_survey_marital["MARITAL STATUS"].value_counts().plot(kind='pie').autopct("'%1.1f%%'")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`autopct` is actually a parameter of [`pandas.Series.plot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3.0/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.html), not a function of the `matplotlib.axes.Axes` object that is returned by that function.

What you’re doing is the equivalent of:

```
marital_chart = market_survey_marital["MARITAL STATUS"].value_counts().plot(kind='pie')
marital_chart.autopct('%1.1f%%')
```

You should try the following instead:

```
marital_chart = market_survey_marital["MARITAL STATUS"].value_counts().plot(kind='pie', autopct='%1.1f%%')
```